# What's the difference between Mysql and SQLite database in android app development?

Tags: android

I am new to android development. I need to create an app having login and register pages..but I'm confuse a little bit between two types of databases Mysql and SQLite.

I just what to know when  to use SQLite  and  Mysql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between MySQL/SQLite/etc databases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838913/difference-between-mysql-sqlite-etc-databases)

Answer (score 1):

My sql is server side data base and if you want to use my sql then you need to call web service .

SQLite Database  is light weighted data base used in mobile as local data base.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite Database is an lite weighted edition its made for an android. It is in-builded in android studio itself. So there is no need to install it newly but MySQL is an Oracle database. Marketed as cost effective. SQLite is not as much of a SQL server. It is really just a database system. The databases can be embedded in applications